# round robin job scheduling w/ page faults

Tags: operating-system, jobs, job-scheduling, round-robin, page-fault

I have a list of jobs with Job#, CPU Time, Arrival time, page faults.  I eventually need to code the process in java but for now i'm just trying to understand how it processes through the jobs with a 10ms time quantum and accounts for the page faults.  I've tried working the first three jobs to no success whats so ever I get hung up when a job happens to start back up but has an immediate page fault.  Does it start and keep running or go back immediately to the waiting queue.  If any one knows how these jobs should be laid out on a time-line i would appreciate it.

Here's the first 3 jobs:

```
Job #   ///Arrival time//  ///CPU TIME//       ///Page Faults//              
J1           ///0//           ///90//          ///7,27,73,86//            
J2           ///1//           ///39//              ///12//            
J3           ///2//           ///195//     ///11,31,73,94,120,134,183//
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your question, one can't frame an answer as :-

1. You haven't mentioned that which Page-Replacement Algorithm is being implemented.
2. If the time-quantum is 10 ms,it's just impossible to achieve page fault with only 3 jobs at the time 7,11,27,31,etc.
3. Even if you had only 3 jobs, then also page faults will only occur in the multiples of 10,except where the jobs are finished.

Please correct the ambiguous question and post(edit) again!